# Shortest way syntaxically to add row datas to a datatable in .NET 2 and .NET 3+

Tags: c#, ado.net

I know I can do this

```
string id = "123";
string name = "John";
DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow["Id"] = id;
dataRow["Name"] = name;
```

I succeeded also with

```
dataTable.Rows.Add("123");
```

only when there is one single column I can't see syntax for multiple columns:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add("123", "John");
```

What's the syntax  I need to be compatible with .NET 2 but also interested to know for 3+

Comment: FYI: It's spelled syntactically.

Comment: Thanks I'm not english native :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the third example you listed works for .NET 2 and above:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add("123","John");
```

Since .NET 2, the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) method that takes an `object[]` has had the argument marked with the `params` keyword, so there is no need to create an array; just pass in the values as separate arguments.

Comment: ok finally it works I made some mistake by forgetting to convert row value to tostring

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dtStudent = new DataTable();
//Add new column
dtStudent.Columns.AddRange(
    new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("SlNo", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("RollNumber", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("DateOfJoin", typeof(DateTime)),
    new DataColumn("Place", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Course", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("Remark", typeof(string))
});
// Add value to the related column 
dtStudent.Rows.Add(1, "10001", DateTime.Now, "Bhubaneswar", "MCA", "Good");
```

Comment: I have removed the blog link from the answer as it doesn't provide any additional information. See [Is it acceptable to promote your own blog?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog) and [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: I downvoted this question since it does not add any value to this Question. The problem is already solved and this is just an answer with code an no explanation whatsoever.